# Windows: Launch menu entry/option of an app via a keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, command-line-arguments

Here is the properties info/data (via [Winlister](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/winlister.html)) of an app's (here, Network Time) Properties window/pop-up (here, launched via right click menu/option, see screenshot).

[image]

[image]

What info of The Properties window (1st images - Winlister)can be used as command line switch so as to launch the Network Time app's properties (or any other windows app) window via windows keyboard shortcut dialog/editor without having to right click the menu option of apps tray icon.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Unclear : Launch the Properties dialog of what? How would you select the app without using the mouse?

Comment: @harrymc In the second screenshot/image you can see the properties list-item (marked in red) in the right click menu list of Network Time software's https://www.timesynctool.com/ tray icon. That spawns/launches the Properties Dialog of Network Time Software

Comment: The only useful stuff is `C:\Program Files (x86)\NetTime\NetTime.exe`, which I suppose doesn't launch the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

My short (opinionated) answer: AHK.
With Auto Hot Key you can create a keyboard shortcut to click a system tray icon and simulate keyboard / mouse navigation.

You will need to learn the scripting language, though. It's not an ready-to-use solution.